# Creating nested objects when iterating collection

Tags: c#, loops, collections

Is it possible to iterate collection and create nested objects while iterating?  I have the following flat list:

```
TOOLID    FACTORY     MACHINE     MODULE
1         facta       123         abc
2         facta       123         def
3         facta       123         ghi
4         facta       789         jkl
5         facta       789         mno
6         factb       456         abc
7         factb       456         def
8         factb       456         ghi
9         factb       456         jkl
10        factb       456         mno
```

I have the following classes defined:

```
public class Tool
{
    public List<Factory> Factories { get; set; }    
}
public class Factory
{    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
}
public class Machine
{    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}
```

So the flat file would create a Tool object with a collection of Factories (i.e. 'facta' and 'factb').  'facta' Factory would contain a collection of machines (i.e. '123' and 789').  '123' machine inside 'facta' would contain a collection of Modules (i.e. 'abc', 'def', 'ghi'), so forth and so on...

JSON representation of what I'm thinking:

```html
{
 "factory": [
  {   
   "name": "facta",
   "machine": [
    {  
     "name": "123",
     "modules": [
      { "name" : "abc"},
      { "name" : "def"},
      { "name" : "ghi"}
     ]
    },
    {     
     "name": "789",
     "modules": [
      { "name" : "jkl"},
      { "name" : "mno"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {   
   "name": "factb",
   "machine": [
    {     
     "name": "456",
     "modules": [
      { "name" : "abc"},
      { "name" : "def"},
      { "name" : "ghi"},
      { "name" : "jkl"},
      { "name" : "mno"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: what structure are you using to hold the flat list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is one way of doing it

EDIT: once you understand the workings of my code, you can condense everything into a single Linq line:

```
to = new Tool();
input.GroupBy(a => a[1]).ToList().ForEach(a =>
    { fa = new Factory($"{a.Key}"); a.GroupBy(b => b[2]).ToList().ForEach(b =>
        { ma = new Machine($"{b.Key}"); b.GroupBy(c => c[3]).ToList().ForEach(c =>
            { mo = new Module($"{c.Key}"); ma.Modules.Add(mo); }); fa.Machines.Add(ma); }); to.Factories.Add(fa); });
```

Original Code:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tool to;
        Factory fa;
        Machine ma;
        Module mo;
        List<ArrayList> input = new List<ArrayList>();

        input.Add(new ArrayList() { 1, "facta", 123, "abc" });
        input.Add(new ArrayList() { 2, "facta", 123, "def" });
        input.Add(new ArrayList() { 3, "facta", 123, "ghi" });
        input.Add(new ArrayList() { 4, "facta", 789, "jkl" });
        input.Add(new ArrayList() { 5, "facta", 789, "mno" });
        input.Add(new ArrayList() { 6, "factb", 456, "abc" });
        input.Add(new ArrayList() { 7, "factb", 456, "def" });
        input.Add(new ArrayList() { 8, "factb", 456, "ghi" });
        input.Add(new ArrayList() { 9, "factb", 456, "jkl" });
        input.Add(new ArrayList() { 10, "factb", 456, "mno" });

        //[0] = ToolId / [1] = FactoryName / [2] = MachineName / [3] = ModuleName

        var factories = input.GroupBy(a => a[1]);
        to = new Tool();

        foreach (var factory in factories)
        {
            fa = new Factory($"{factory.Key}");
            var machines = factory.GroupBy(a => a[2]);
            foreach (var machine in machines)
            {
                ma = new Machine($"{machine.Key}");
                var modules = machine.GroupBy(a => a[3]);
                foreach (var module in modules)
                {
                    mo = new Module($"{module.Key}");
                    ma.Modules.Add(mo);
                }
                fa.Machines.Add(ma);
            }
            to.Factories.Add(fa);
        }
    }
}
public class Tool
{
    public List<Factory> Factories { get; set; }
    public Tool()
    {
        Factories = new List<Factory>();
    }
}
public class Factory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
    public Factory(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Machines = new List<Machine>();
    }
}
public class Machine
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Module> Modules { get; set; }
    public Machine(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Modules = new List<Module>();
    }
}
public class Module
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Module(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your flat list is an array inside of an array:

`string[][] flatList = new string[10][4];`

I am also assuming you have a Module class as well?

```
public class Module
{    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You would start by initializing and populating the four separate entities that exist in the first line of data:

```
Tool tool = new Tool(){Factories = new List<Factories>()};
Factory factory = new Factory(){Name = flatList[0][1], Machines = new List< Machine>()};
tool.Factories.Add(factory);
Machine machine = new Machine(){Name = flatList[0][2], Modules = new List<Module>()};
factory.Machines.Add(machine);
Module module = new Module(){Name = flatList[0][3]};
machine.Modules.Add(module);
bool isNewMachine = false;
bool isNewModule = false;
```

Then you would iterate on the remaining lines and create new instances as needed. Because you are building a hierarchical structure, if a new entity is created, all its children entities would automatically be new as well. Hence, the need for `isNewMachine` and `isNewModule`.

IMHO, at this point the code becomes self explanatory.

```
for(int i = 1; i < flatList.Length; i++)
{
    if(factory.Name != flatList[i][1]) //factory is different from previous
    {
        factory = new Factory(){Name = flatList[i][1], Machines = new List< Machine>()};
        tool.Factories.Add(factory);
        isNewMachine = true;
        isNewModule = true;
    }
    if(isNewMachine || machine.Name != flatList[i][2]) //machine is different from previous
    {
        machine = new Machine(){Name = flatList[][2], Modules = new List<Module>()};
        factory.Machines.Add(machine);
        isNewMachine = false;
        isNewModule = true;
    }
    if(isNewModule || module.Name != flatList[i][3]) //module is different than previous
    {
        module = new Module(){Name = flatList[0][3]};
        machine.Modules.Add(module);
        isNewModule = false;
    }
}
```

Also, depending on the .NET framework version you are using, you can reduce the amount of code by instantiating a class's List property automatically. For example, your `Tool` entity would look like this:

```
public class Tool
{
    public List<Factory> Factories { get; set; } = new List<Factory>();
}
```

Then you could remove all the lines of code currently required to instantiate each instanced List:

```
 ... ], Modules = new List<Module>()
```

Answer (score 0):

out of the box, I don't know anything that can make this.
For sure, it is possible.

You could create a class for the listitems

```
public class FlatItem
{
    public int ToolId {get;set;}
    public string Factory {get;set;}
    public int Machine {get;set;}
    public string Module {get;set;}
}

List<FlatItem> flatitemlist = ... // get your flatlist into this list
```

and then, I'd recommend you, to work with `System.Linq`s `GroupBy` extension (or linq query `group by`) like this here:

```
var result = flatitemlist
                .GroupBy(g => g.Factory)
                .Select(t => t
                    .GroupBy(g => g.Machine)
                    .Select(x => x
                        .GroupBy(y => y.Module))).ToList();
```

so you get the structure and you can iterate through the items.

maybe, also take a look at this:

```
var result = flatitemlist.GroupBy(x => new {x.Factory, x.Machine, x.Module});
```